# How to remove prefix from Flyway migration name?

Tags: java, spring, flyway

By default, Flyway searches for migrations that start with "V" in the folder `db/migration`, for example:
`V1_1_0__init_schema.sql`

However, my migrations have the following naming pattern (and I can't change my migrations name):
`20210902193819451__init_schema.sql`

How can I remove the letter "V" from the default behavior of Flyway, so that my migrations can be found?

I've already tried to set the following property in my configurations file:
`spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix: ""`, but that doesn't work, and I get the following error:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.flywaydb.core.api.exception.FlywayValidateException:  Validate
> failed: Migrations have failed validation

Comment: I tested the configuration on `spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix: ""` with the same file format as yours and it worked. Could you elaborate more on your resource path, usage, and stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding the following configs to my `application.yml` file:

```
spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix: "20"
spring.flyway.sql-migration-separator: "_"
```

Instead of removing the prefix, I've simply replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Flyway is a Spring managed bean. Your configuration should be `spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V` as described [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#sql-based-migrations).

Caution, as database migrations are meant to have different prefixes for [versioning](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/sqlMigrationPrefix), [undo](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/undoSqlMigrationPrefix), and [repeatable](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/repeatableSqlMigrationPrefix) migrations. You should also note that entity validation might come from Flyway (from table `flyway_schema_history`), which checks from your script's checksum, and Hibernate, which checks from your `@Entity` model.

Comment: Yes, I am using the property `spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix` (I've edited my question). But the problem is that I want to remove the `V` from the default behavior.

Comment: @Caroline could you try to use a flyway configuration file to change the config? The format would be `db/migration/conf/flyway.conf` and using `flyway.sql-migration-prefix` specified [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile.html).

Comment: Isn't it the same to set the configs using `spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix` (which I already have) and create a file `flyway.conf` and start using `flyway.sql-migration-prefix`?